# Can an update statement do all the follow?

Tags: sql

I'm doing the revision questions for my database course and I can't work out which question is false.

1. The keyword SET can be followed by multiple assignment expressions
2. If the join operation is used, an update statement can update multiple tables
3. The keyword update is followed by one and only one table name
4. The where clause can be omitted.

I'm thinking no 3 is the false one but I'm not sure why. I'm guessing where attributes are the same it can join multiple tables.

Comment: I think you mean which statement is false correct? Why don't you write statements of each type and see if they work?

Comment: "If the join operation is used, an update statement can update multiple tables" That seems to be dependent on which database you use.

Comment: Yes, I meant false sorry

Comment: I think **3** is also database specific. As usual with SQL questions, you need to specify which database you're targeting.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server, I believe:

1. The keyword SET can be followed by multiple assignment expressions  = True
2. If the join operation is used, an update statement can update multiple tables = False
3. The keyword update is followed by one and only one table name = True
4. The where clause can be omitted. = True